# App is getting crashed when I update app through UpdateManager using hockeyapp

Tags: android, crash, hockeyapp

My android app is getting crashed while I update the app through hockeyapp UpdateManager.

Here is my update code:

```
private void checkForUpdates() {
        // Remove this for store builds!
        UpdateManager.register(this, getResources().getString(R.string.hockey_app_id), new UpdateManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNoUpdateAvailable() {
                super.onNoUpdateAvailable();

                // no update is available ->  load login screen
//                setFragment(R.id.container_login, new LoginFragment());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdateAvailable(JSONArray data, String url) {
                super.onUpdateAvailable(data, url);
            }
        }, true);
    }
```

it is showing update dialog but when i clicked update then after 100% loading app is getting crashed. Here is the crash log:

> onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
>                                                                                                  com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from
>   input stream
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem by searching different documentations of hockeyApp. 
Here is solution of above problem:

Check for updates method:

```
private void checkForUpdates() {

        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

        UpdateManager.register(this, getResources().getString(R.string.hockey_app_id), new UpdateManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNoUpdateAvailable() {
                super.onNoUpdateAvailable();

                // no update is available ->  load login screen
//                setFragment(R.id.container_login, new LoginFragment());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdateAvailable(JSONArray data, String url) {
                super.onUpdateAvailable(data, url);
            }
        }, true);
    }
```

Also need to unregister Updatemanager in activity onPause() or onDestroy() method.

```
private void unregisterManagers() {
        UpdateManager.unregister();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterManagers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterManagers();
    }
```

This is the complete solution of hockeyApp in app update feature.